# Cannot resize element and overflow is not available

Tags: json

I'am trying to use `amp-list` custom Element for dynamically rendering data. I am using `layout=responsive` on element for make it responsive in different devices, I followed sample examples given in ampbyexapmle site. Once I run the page height is not adding to respective `amp-list` Element instead I'm getting the title has a error. I'm new to Google-amp may I get any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: please post what you tried